# Cannot call sass or ruby command's in bat file

Tags: ruby, sass

I am trying to run the sass --watch command in a bat file like so

```
@echo off
set path="C:\styles"
sass --watch %path%

pause
```

I am getting the error 'sass' is not recognized as an internal or external command etc....

I get the same issue if i try calling ruby.exe

I can run sass and ruby in a command line window and it works fine. Ruby version 1.9.3.3p362, Sass version 3.2.5 (Media Mark), Windows 7

I have tried adding 'call' before the sass command and running as administrator but no success so far.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the executable files cannot be located.

It could have something to do with you overriding the path - try using another variable name for your temp needs!

So, either ensure that the folders of the executables are set properly in your `$PATH` environment variable or call the executables with their full path. For example:

```
"C:/MyFolder/Ruby 1.9.x/ruby.exe" ...
```

or

```
"C:/your path/of/sass.exe" -- watch ...
```

Comment: Thanks, the path variable was the issue. I changed  and all working well.